Solana program deployment always failed
I have tried to deploy my program into Solana Devnet. But I have never ever succeeded just with once execution for the deployment. Each time I have to recover the KEY, and deploy the program again. I always needed to do the deployment twice to successfully deploy my program. Although finally I can deploy the program, but why it always need to do the deployment two times. It is some bothering, can it be improved?

Please provide some more info about the commands you're running for your devnet deployment. It's tough to debug with just your question unfortunately!
